# Convert decimal amount to text string fraction in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fractions

I have a value returned as a number, with could be decimal number e.g. "1.15".

However, I need to format all numbers **in a range** to a given fraction.  For example, all numbers greater than 0 but less than .2 I want to return "1/8".

I already started to do this as a series of if/else statements, but I was wondering if there was a smarter and neater way.

```
if (amt > 0 && amt <= .2){
    q = '1/8';
} else if (amt > .2 && amt <= .3){
    q = '1/4';
}  else if (amt > .3 && amt <= .4){
    q = '1/3';
}  else if (amt > .4 && amt <= .5){
    q = '1/2';
} else if (amt > .5 && amt <= .7){
    q = '2/3';
} else if (amt > .7 && amt <= .8){
    q = '3/4';
} else if (amt > .8 && amt <= 1.0){
    q = '7/8';
} else if (amt > 1 && amt <= 1.1){
    q = '1';
} etc.....
```

Comment: Why are using so mane `else if` statements. Why not a `switch case`?

Comment: switch case only accepts one value and implies equals (=).

Comment: @joseph how yu wil give switch case if value is like .22 .23 .25 .27

Comment: What isn't clear is, what happens when you reach a value greater than 1? Are you going to return things like "1 1/2" for 1.5?

Comment: @Diodeus: That's true, but you can trick it into evaluting stuff for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9XWAA/ , although the main idea of a `switch` is the *simplify* matters, not complicate them ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code into a function, and you can `return` from the correct branch and skip all the `else` statements, which cleans things up pretty dramatically:

```
function toFraction(amt) {
  if (amt > 0 && amt <= .2) return '1/8';
  if (amt <= .3) return '1/4';
  if (amt <= .4) return '1/3';
  if (amt <= .5) return '1/2';
  // etc
}
```

Comment: This code will return '1/4' if the input is less than zero; need to start with `if (amt <=0) {//do something}`. Having said that, this is definitely the type of structure I would use, though I think the biggest improvement here is not so much putting it in its own function as the removal of the pointless minimum value tests within each test (which of course aren't needed provided you test in the right order).

Comment: @nnnn The code only does what the original sample code does. There are certain assumptions made about the value of `amt` as passed to the function.

Comment: But it doesn't do the same thing: the original sample has an undefined result for 0 or less, since that doesn't match any of the if cases we are shown, while your code has a defined result of '1/4' since it does match the second case...I just wanted to be sure the original poster didn't forget to handle 0 and negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

[Ratio.js](https://github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js) has a function called `.toQuantityOf()`.

`.toQuantityOf()` returns a new fraction after converting the current value of the fraction to it's approximate value based on the provided units. If multiple units are passed as arguments, then the closest match to the original value will be returned.

`.toString()` returns the fraction as a string.

```
var fraction = Ratio.parse("1.15").toQuantityOf(2,3,4,8);
fraction.toString() == "9/8";
```

`.toLocaleString()` will return mixed numbers if needed.

```
fraction.toLocaleString() == "1 1/8";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform mathematical operations on `amt` to transform it to an integer value within a range, then use that as an index for an array lookup to get the fraction text.

That can be simple if your ranges are equal, but since you have some 1/10th (0.3 to 0.4) and some 2/10ths (0.5 to 0.7) it's a little more complex, more than just multiply by 10.

---

```
fractional = {
    fractions: [ "1/8", "1/8", "1/4", "1/3", "1/2", "2/3", "2/3", "3/4", "7/8", "1" ],
    toFraction: function(amt) {
        return this.fractions[(""+(amt*10)).split('.')[0]];
    }
};

alert(fractional.toFraction(0.37));
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but doesn't work correctly since `alert(fractional.toFraction(.5));` gives you 2/3 (the sixth item in the array).  Also, it breaks when there are numbers over 1 (e.g. 1.35)

Comment: @Steve - yeah, simply multiplying by 10 is hardly ever the right thing to do, as I mentioned originally in my answer. I usually have to do something like add half-a-unit, multiply, round to get the correct number. Otherwise, I'm not sure I put the correct text for the fractions in the right spots in the array but that can easily be adjusted, and finally, this technique necessarily limits you to a range but so does the accepted answer. Either case would have to deal with `n > 1` by handling the fractional part separately from the whole number.

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiple `amt` by 10 and get the integer part
2. From an array that you have previous constructed - look up the corresponding string!

NB - That array is fixed - so is static