# Js Numbers - fractions

Tags: javascript, numbers

I want this:

In website have `var number = 0.33` and I want `var second = fractions of variable 'number'`, and if "number" fractions change : `second` will change.

But how?

Comment: what you had tried before .. please mention

Comment: I is not tried before.

Comment: Please help from initially. I don't tried

Comment: ok Follow this Link - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783869/convert-a-decimal-number-to-a-fraction-rational-number)

Comment: Thanks. But please send this link as answer.

Comment: I posted the answer try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Erik Garrison's [**fraction.js**](https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js) library to do that and more fractional operations.

```
var second = new Fraction(.033);
console.log(second.numerator + '/' + second.denominator);
```

Comment: This is not work: Error is  "Fraction is not defined". Why?

Comment: I will upvote this only if work. But I have a problem. ERROR: Fraction is not defined. I upvoted this now, but why this is not work.

Comment: you use the fraction.js library

Comment: Sorry. I is not view link.