# How do I turn a decimal into a improper fraction JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have something like this

```
  function myFunction1() {
var aEquation = prompt("What is a? (if it is not there write 1)");
var bEquation = prompt("What is b?");
var cEquation = prompt("What is C?");
  var x10 = prompt("What is your first X coordinate?");
  var x20 = prompt("What is your second X coordinate?");
  var x30 = prompt("What is your thrid X coordinate?");
  var x40 = prompt("What is your fourth X coordinate?");
  var x50 = prompt("What is your fifth X coordinate?");
  var x60 = prompt("What is your sixth X coordinate?");
  var x70 = prompt("What is your seventh X coordinate?");
  var x80 = prompt("What is your eighth X coordinate?");
  var x90 = prompt("What is your ninth X coordinate?");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your equation is:" + " " + aEquation + "x^2" + " " + "+" + " " + bEquation + "x" + " " + "+" + " " + cEquation;
  document.getElementById("Answerone").innerHTML = (eval(x10)*eval(x10)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x10)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answertwo").innerHTML = (eval(x20)*eval(x20)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x20)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answerthree").innerHTML = (eval(x30)*eval(x30)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x30)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answerfour").innerHTML = (eval(x40)*eval(x40)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x40)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answerfive").innerHTML = (eval(x50)*eval(x50)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x50)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answersix").innerHTML = (eval(x60)*eval(x60)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x60)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answerseven").innerHTML = (eval(x70)*eval(x70)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x70)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answereight").innerHTML = (eval(x80)*eval(x80)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x80)*1)+(cEquation*1);
  document.getElementById("Answernine").innerHTML = (eval(x90)*eval(x90)*aEquation)+(bEquation*eval(x90)*1)+(cEquation*1); 
}
```

I know I can use functions but I'm doing it this way right now. Currently, if I put a number like 3/2 in for x10, x20, etc, the answer will come out correct but in a decimal form like 0.5, 1.75, etc. Is there any way to make them all come out as improper fractions? Instead of 0.5, 1.75, I want it to display 1/2, 7/4 respectively. Thanks!!

Comment: BTW, I wrote this so I can answer my Kumon questions more quickly xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a decimal number to a fraction / rational number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783869/convert-a-decimal-number-to-a-fraction-rational-number)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is possible for non recurring fractions of course.

Take the numerator and the denominator separately- like 1.75 as 175 and 100, then find the [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of these two numbers.

Then divide both the numbers by the gcd and format the new numerator and denominator on your own in the a/b form.

Hope this helps !

EDIT:

You can write a small script like this. U have to do this for every number.
NOTE: THIS DOESNT GIVE CORRECT RESULTS FOR RECURRING DECIMALS.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    convert(".00033")
}

function gcd( a,  b)
{
    var r = a%b;
    while(r != 0)
    {
        a = b;
        b = r;
        r = a%b;
    }
    return b;
}

function convert( inp)
{
    var a="", b = 1, flag = 0;
    for( i = 0; i<inp.length; i++)
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            console.log("bing");
            b = b*10;
        }
        if(inp.charAt(i) != '.')
        {
            a += inp.charAt(i)
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 1
        }


    }
    a = parseInt(a);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    var x = gcd(a, b);
    console.log(a/x + "/" + b/x)
}
</script>
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but I have no idea how to write it in JavaScript. Is it possible if you write a short example?